# Find $a$ for which $y\ge x^2+4a^2,x\ge y^2+4a^2$ has only one solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For what $a$ does this system of inequalities have only one solution?

$$
\begin{cases}y\ge x^2+4a^2\\x\ge y^2+4a^2\end{cases}
$$
So, I have tried getting $y$ from the first equation then putting it into second, but then I have two quadratic and $x$, which of these quadratics are the first term? I know that I have to put it into $\Delta=0$. But don't really get which of them are first, second etc.
Even tried subtracting second to first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0), x_0\ne y_0$ is a solution then $(y_0,x_0)$ is also a solution. So in order to have only one solution, one must have $x=y$. Plugging $y=x$ in the first equation one gets:
$$x^2-x+4a^2\le 0$$
Which has an unique solution iff $\Delta=1-(4a)^2=0$ which is equivalent to $a=\pm\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,y)$ is a solution so is $(y,x)$, so for one solution we need $x=y$ – we thus seek $a$ for which $y=x^2+4a^2$ is tangent to $y=x$, i.e. $x^2-x+4a^2$ has one solution, hence zero discriminant. Here $\Delta=1-16a^2=0$, so $a=\pm\frac14$ where the only solution is $(x,y)=(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: Not quite (and I dislike that shortcut of arguing about reflection, because it can lead to erroneous conclusions like when we allow for multiple solutions). I rather you argue that if we have a solution $ (a, b) $ with $ a \neq b$, then we also have $ (a, b)$ as a distinct solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin there, pushed in.

Answer (score 2):

We have,

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}y^2≥\left(x^2+4a^2\right)^2≥0\\y^2≤x-4a^2,\thinspace x≥4a^2\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\left(x^2+4a^2\right)^2≤y^2≤x-4a^2\\
\implies &\left(x^2+4a^2\right)^2≤x-4a^2 \\
\implies &16a^4+a^2(8x^2+4)+(x^4-x)≤0\\
\implies &\left(4a^2+\left(x^2+\frac 12\right)\right)^2≤\left(x+\frac 12\right)^2\\
\implies &x^2-x+4a^2≤0\\
\implies &\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2≤\frac{1-16a^2}{4}\end{align}$$

Similary, we have

$$\begin{align}\left(y^2+4a^2\right)^2≤y-4a^2\\
\implies \left(y-\frac 12\right)^2≤\frac{1-16a^2}{4}\end{align}$$

We see that, if $x,y$ are unique then

$$16a^2=1\iff a=±\frac 14$$

which implies,

$$x=y=\frac 12.$$

Comment: Well, thank you very much! It was somewhat hard to understand that solution, obviously, there was no chance I could have solved it like this, yet.